# Can't add Visual C++ template project in Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express

Don't know if this is related to the fact that I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express, but when trying the first step in the link below I can't find the template Visual C++. I tried to download Visual C++ 2010 Express but still no luck.

Does anyone have a work around for this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550(v=VS.92).aspx

EDIT:
I have now tried to create this DLL in Visual C++ 2010 Express instead. When following the guide from the link above I get stuck when I should add resource to the project (Step 2 under 'Create the Language-Neutral Resource Strings for Your Application'). The menu item is greyed out/disabled.

Comment: Which VS2010 Express are you using?

Comment: It's called Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. Version: WPDTRTMRel - 40219.209. Was that theinformation you wanted?

Comment: More or less... And what goes wrong with the C++ version?

Comment: I'm failing when I'm about to add resources. The menu alternative "Project > Add resource" is greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

You will need the C++ edition of VS Express to create this Win32 Resource DLL. I assume that that is possible.

And then add the Project (might work) or the resulting file (should work) to your Phone project.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to create the DLL in Visual C++ and then copy it to the regular project folder. But I can't "Add resource" to this C++ project.

Answer (score -3):

as far as I know you cannot create or build a native C/C++ project in Visual Studio Express. As I understand it, the Visual Studio Express is similar to a demo version that only allows you to create projects that use the .NET framework.

To create and build native C/C++ projects you need the retail Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: Or VS Express C++, http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: @Komyg Sure there are things you can't do with the Express version, e.g. create MFC applicatons. But you exaggerate. And it's not a demo!

Comment: Sorry, I had bad experiences with Visual Studio Express 2008 a while back. I couldn't build any native C++ applications with it and it took me sometime to figure out that that just wasn't possible (I was very new to Visual Studio back then). Anyway I thought that the same applied to Visual Studio Express 2010...

Comment: There was also an express version of Visual C++ for 2008 editions. You can get express versions of a lot of Microsoft products, such as Web Developer and Windows Phone Development. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).